# how to set max_execution_time php-fpm docker image?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, fastcgi, fpm

I am using docker image for php5.6-fpm from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/.

When I check php.ini location in phpinfo() it says it is /usr/local/etc/php, but when I look into that path there is no php.ini located there.

Now I want to change max_execution_time php variable. How can I do that in custom docker image?

Comment: suppose you use apache2, the path is   php/arache2/php.ini

Comment: You do it the same way you always would.  There's nothing magical about Docker.  Also, are you confusing the host filesystem with the container filessytem?  The php.ini file is in the container, not the host filesystem.

Comment: docker is designed to be rebuilt easily and often, edit your Dockerfile, do your modification, build it again, and run it

Comment: @GordonM I have checked running container's filesystem using docker exec -it containerId /bin/bash and it didn't show any php.ini in /usr/local/etc/php

Comment: @KrisRoofe I am using php-fpm variant of php docker image and using another nginx container as reverse proxy

Comment: @user2915097 The question is where should I change in Dockerfile as there is no existing php.ini in that docker image

Answer (score 8):

What you do is, you derive from the official FPM image and then use RUN+sed to change the value, e.g.:

```
FROM php:7.1

RUN sed -e 's/max_execution_time = 30/max_execution_time = 100/' -i /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

Please ensure the path `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini` is correct in your case, it depends on the image used, i did not verify above the php:7.1 one.

Hint: When you need to change a lot of values, you might rather want to simply use your own php.ini in your image

```
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

But thats just in case, changing just a few values can be done with sed

Answer (score 8):

add following line to Dockerfile

```
RUN echo 'max_execution_time = 120' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-maxexectime.ini;
```

then

```
docker-compose build 
docker-compose up
```

or

```
docker build 
docker start your_machine_name
```

provided PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR = /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d.
You can check it in running

`<? phpinfo();`

should say

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files | /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

Answer (score 3):

**Easy solution:**

1. Navigate your docker image and find the configuration that mostly adapts to your needs between `php.ini-development`and `php.ini-production`(the first on may be  more indicated for logging, second for production-like env.).
2. Copy the configuration file in your project folder, or where you keep the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`

I'm using the `php:7.4.12-apache`image as starting point, the php.ini file must be copied into `/usr/local/etc/php/`, and it will be loaded automatically on next start.

3. Now edit any property you need into the configuration file, and save it as `php.ini`
4. Finally, the file must be copied into the image / container, see how in the following lines.

### **Dockerfile (to copy into image)**

Add `COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`

**OR**

### **docker-compose.yml (to copy into container)**

```
services:
    php-apache-dev:

        ...

        volumes:
            - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

        ...
```

*this configuration has the php.ini in same folder as docker-compose.yml*

Note: honestly I prefer to copy into container, because I can edit the configuration and simply re-launch the container, without rebuilding the image, but it's up to you.

I find this solution more useful in development, it's simpler, and you can edit many properties, not just only one.

Happy coding!